Why doesn't the vapour pressure exceed the external pressure as boiling begins?
Boiling point is the temperature at which the vapour pressure equals the external pressure and it becomes possible for a bubble to form without getting squeezed and allows it to rise to the surface of the liquid and eventually to burst into the atmosphere.
Doubt : Won't this increase the vapour pressure? Just the moment when vapour pressure equals external pressure - the boiling hasn't begun yet - the vapour state and the liquid state are in equilibrium  i.e. the Rate of Evaporation = Rate of Condensation. This means a certain number of molecules are evaporating as well as getting condensed at that temperature. My thinking is, since the liquid begins to boil it adds to the number of molecules getting evaporated this would mean the vapour pressure increases over time. But, tbis is clearly not the case as I have read at many places. Please explain to me where I am wrong. (The above phenomenon takes place in an open vessel).
What I have read :

As the vapour pressure equals the external pressure, the liquid begins to boil and over time the entire liquid turns to vapour. But the boiling of liquid doesn't affect the vapour pressure. The vapour pressure stays the same as the external pressure; countering it - allowing more and more liquid molecules to escape into the atmosphere by turning into gas.

Another Doubt : What happens when the last drop of liquid is left at the boiling pt.? How does it turn into vapour? (My reasoning is that even at this instance the vapour pressure will exist and a particular number of molecules will be existing in equilibrium between the phases. Just as the few molecules still in equilibrium condense back into liquid they will boil off as the liquid is still is at the boiling temp.) Am I right?

It absolutely does increase above ambient pressure above B.P. However, in an open container, the vapor is vented, so the liquid remains at B.P. And in a closed container, it's a pressure cooker.

You have any idea how many q. on the topic are here? Here's a sample https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/38653?lq=1

Additionally, it can begin boil violently until vapor pressure and external pressure rebalance. Typical case is attaching a cold water reservoir to e.g. "water" vacuum pump, based on Bernoulli equation.

Above boiling a liquid's point (B.P.), the vapor in the bubble absolutely does increase above ambient pressure, or the bubble could not have pushed away the liquid, creating that void. However, that over-pressure exists only until the bubble expands, which might be just microseconds or milliseconds. As the bubble forms, it expands, and the pressure equalizes with the ambient pressure in the liquid. In an open container, the hot vapor is vented, so the liquid remains at B.P.
Expansion can occur invisibly, as when liquid helium boils, or with a bit of noise, called "bumping", or, in very still, evenly-heated liquid without a source of nucleation, it can cause a violent explosion of the superheated liquid. On reheating water in a clean glass mug in a microwave oven, I've had an accidental steam explosion that blew open the oven door! Luckily, I was far enough not to get scalded. That water might have reached 105° or 110° C, without boiling, before flashing into steam all at once. Once that steam escaped the mug, it dropped to ambient pressure, and the remaining liquid water, to 100° C.
A closed container is a pressure cooker. Pressure increases, though active boiling ceases when the increased pressure of the vapor above the liquid prevents bubbles from forming. Hydrothermal vents in the depths might not boil, though the water temperature can exceed 400° C, because of the pressure of the water column.
BTW, boiling is effectively to cavitation, in which the ambient liquid pressure drops below its vapor pressure.

Boiling is a physical phenomenon that happens when an evaporating liquid is in a steady state with its pure vapor and the vapor is doing work against an external applied force. When liquid is continuing to evaporate and the vapor is continually expanding against the atmosphere the vapor pressure MUST be higher than the atmosphere and the temperature of the liquid-vapor interface must be higher than the actual equilibrium boiling point The actual equilibrium BP is when or where the liquid and vapor exist and the interface is doing no work against the atmosphere, the pressures are equal. This situation can be difficult to attain empirically so many techniques have been developed to accurately measure boiling points, Several are usually outlined in Experimental P Chem texts.
